# Multithread Upsert in Neo4j

Tags: multithreading, neo4j

I am working with Neo4j in a stream monitoring application. My stream is really light, something like 8 to 10 transactions per second.

When I save my transactions in Neo4j , as soon as they arrive, with more than one thread I have a deadlock error and some Nodes and relationships are not saved.

Is there any kind of solution, in configuration  or code, I can use to solve this kind of problem ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Here is some general info on how to avoid and handle deadlocks.

1. You have to write your code or Cypher queries in a way that avoids deadlocks.

   - [The Deadlocks doc page](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/transactions-deadlocks.html) provides some info on this, especially if you are using the Java API.
   - You should also be aware of neo4j's [default locking behavior](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/transactions-locking.html).
   - Note that there is [an outstanding neo4j Issue](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/6914) about the inconsistent order in which nodes are locked when creating versus deleting a relationship.
   - When using Cypher, there is no explicit node/relationship locking support. You can only rely on the default locking behavior. However, [the Isolation levels doc page](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/transactions-isolation.html) describes a workaround that can be helpful.
2. It may be impossible to prevent deadlocks altogether, but you can definitely make them less likely.
3. When you get the deadlock status code `"Neo.TransientError.Transaction.DeadlockDetected"` (or, in fact, any [status code](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/status-codes.html) beginning with `"Neo.TransientError"`), you should retry later (ideally after a randomized interval).